# Compile C codes with ANSI in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, ansi-c

I need my code to be fully up to ANSI standards like using this command line in Unix System:

```
gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic code.c -o code...
```

How can I (manually) compile my code with those standards or is there any settings in Eclipse that can achieve this standard?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a specific problem?

Comment: Yeh, my code run as usual in Eclipse but when I compile in Unix with that command line, ANSI informs lots of mis-standards and does not compile. The command line is what I must use in code demo so it cannot change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project\Properties\C/C++ Build\Settings

Then find:

'Miscellaneous' and check 'Support ANSI Programs',
'Warnings' and check 'Pedantic', 'Pedantic warnings as error', 'All warnings',
'Debugging' and choose preferred debug standards,
'Optimisations' then select any level.